# Arduino - count pulses without interrupt

Tags: arduino

I would like to know if there is a way to count digital pulses on an Arduino WITHOUT implementing an interrupt routine.

Further description: I have a sensor that outputs digital pulses proportional to some measurement I want to calculate.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by polling, however that keeps your processor busy, and you should be aware that any state which might last less time than your polling interval could be missed.

Comment: The way to count pulses without an ISR is to use the hardware counters, by periodically processing their state and setting their count limit to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only can you do it without an interrupt handler, you can do it little or no software and handle faster pulse rates that is possible by software polling or interrupt counting.

The Atmel AVR that most Arduinos are based on have counter/timer hardware that will count pulsed in an input pin directly.  All you have to do is configure the hardware for counter operation and read the counter register.  There is a small complexity for 16 bit counters on an 8 bit device, but that is simple to overcome. Arduino configures timers for default PWM operations, but that can be overridden as described [here](http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~markt/ATmega-timers.html)(See the AVR user manual for more detail) - you need to use the timer/counter in CTC mode.

ARM based Arduninos and pretty much any other microcontroller will have similar hardware facilities; some have greater flexibility over which pins may be used for hardware counting.

On the AVR you have 8 and 16 bit counters, if you need larger counts you may have to handle the overflow interrupt.  If you will be polling the counter regularly, you may be able to handle even that without interrupts while being able to poll at a much lower and possibly aperiodic rate than the rate of input pulses simply by polling the overflow flag before the next overflow.

In your case, you probably need to read the pulse count at a regular period that shorter than the time in which the counter will overflow at the maximum expected pulse rate.  So for example if you were using an 8 bit counter and the maximum pulse rate were 1KHz you would need to poll every 256/1000 seconds or shorter, but the greatest precision is afforded by making the period as long as possible.  So for example you might have something like the following (this is not real code, and only a fragment):

```
for(;;)
{
    delayMS( 250 ) ;
    frequency = 4 * readCounter() ;
}
```

An alternative that will get a better linear response but non-deterministic readout would be to poll the overflow flag, and measure the time taken to count a fixed number of pulses and so determine your measurement from the time for a fixed count rather than the count for a fixed time.

```
for(;;)
{
    int start = getMillisec() ;

    while( !counterOVF() )
    {
        // Do nothing (or something useful but quick)
    }

    int t = getMillisec() - start ;
    frequency = 256 * t / 1000 ; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your question. If I understood correctly, your first idea consists of couting the pulses by hardware, and the second leaves the processor busy all the time. The problem is that my microcontroller is totally loaded (that's why a simple ISR incrementing a counting variable won't work) and can not be polling as it needs to perform other tasks. Furthermore, I have no more hardware counters available. Are there any other alternatives? I heard it could be possible using analog ports (relying on similarities with PWM). Thank you very much

Comment: In both cases the hardware counter is doing the counting, in the second, my example polls the overflow flag, but that is just to demonstrate the principle, it is not the fundamental solution; it could equally be an interrupt handler - the advantage being that you get one interrupt for every 256 pulses (assuming 8 bit counter) rather than every pulse, so the interrupt overhead is much lower.

Comment: You could use an analogue input only if the sensor output is a fixed frequency PWM (and you added suitable analogue filtering with cut-off somewhat below that frequency), but your question implies that it is a variable frequency rather than PWM (otherwise how would counting pulses help?).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the analog, with a little bit of digital in front of it.
if your input maximum frequency is 1kHz, use this signal to trigger mono-stable (edge triggered) with pulse output of 1ms (1/fmax). Then low pass filter it (R in series, C to ground, and repeat for multi-pole), and finally read analog voltage on that last capacitor. If R*C is relatively small the analog signal will react fast, but have ripples. If it is large, the reaction time will suffer, but the signal will be more stable.